Page numbers have an incorrect "maximum" page
I am having an issue with a Word doc in which my page numbers, of the format "Page ## of ##", do not have the correct maximum page. Specifically, upon reaching page 38, the number states "page 38 of 38", followed by "page 39 of 38", "page 40 of 38", et cetera. Page 38 contains no section breaks, just text and images. I have tried fully deleting the page numbers and re-adding them, as well as the "continue from previous section" option under "format page numbers".
Additionally, when I do eventually start a new section, it keeps the page numbering, but the "of ##" number changes. For example, I have a section that is 4 pages long, which has page numbers "page 45 of 4", "page 46 of 4", et cetera.
Can someone help me fix these numbers? I just want them to count up to the last page, nothing fancy.

https://www.google.com/search?q=word+incorrect+page+count ?

Try the field { DocProperty Pages } instead of the NumPages field.
Otherwise, consider saving a document with the problem on OneDrive or DropBox and posting a link here so we can look at it.  See also: http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html

Word often plays badly with Section Breaks.  Unless you need the Section Breaks to manage format changes, you can swap in Page Breaks instead and that should clear up the issue.
